# Upload a recording to Google Voice as a greeting

Tags: google-voice

Short of putting the phone up to the speaker on my computer, is there a way to get a recorded greeting on Google Voice?

I don't want to have Google Voice call me. I have professionally recorded messages from my company that I would like to use.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is **no**. There are a few hacks around, as previously mentioned by others, but none of them are straight "upload a recording to Google Voice"—there's computer sorcery involved. (Google should add such a feature, though I can see where copyright infringement could become an issue.)

JoshMock's link would be great if Gizmo5 still accepted new account registrations. (I will never understand why Google buys services and then shutters the sign-up section.)

Answer (score 0):

Use your PC. Go to sound options and change the nice setting to line in= sound card instead of mic. Record on GV, play mp3.

Answer (score -2):

Set your primary phone to Google Talk and answer it when you press record. It acts just like a phone and works like a champ.

In fact, I have my broken iphone forward my messages to my Google Voice account which then forwards to Google Talk, so I can use Google Talk to answer my phone.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP specifically says that there already exist recordings to be used and that any technique that suggests ways to record a new message are not desired.

Comment: This is still the best answer nowadays.  What's missing is how to get google talk recording from your system sound without using external wires or holding a speaker up to a microphone.  If you can do that, that's the best quality you'll get without doing some hacking.